# Out of memory error storing large file to SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, memory

I am working on a program that converts any file to binary and then stores it in a sqlite database. I am doing this in VB.Net.

Everything is working fine except when I use a file size of about 200MB. I get:

```
malloc() out of memory
```

Is there the a way to handle this or to stop sqlite from using memory so that it works straight from hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

right now sqlite only support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647..

so i thing you need to implement compressing in your solution if feasible  or restrict the file size

Comment: 2^31-1 is an order of magnitude larger than 200M.

Comment: One thing more part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the maximum number of bytes in a row. (W.R.T) sqlite.org

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that SQLite should be able to cope with 200MB blob.